# React/TypeScript/SPFx forEach and map function issues with complex objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have a problem in rendering React with Dynamic UI.

I found out that one of my components is misbehaving.

I have an object with an array property that I get through props.

The object is similar to the following

Obj:

```
{
  title: "title",
  id: 0,
  rTimes: [
  { idH: 0, hours: 2 }, 
  { idH: 1, hours: 3 }, 
  { idH: 2, hours: 1 }]
};
```

if I log the object with console.log() it shows the correct output but if I iterate with `forEach` on the hours array it becomes weird.

```js
this.props.Obj.rTimes.forEach((rt) => {
  console.log(tr.hours);
});
```

```
=== Console Output ===

0
0
0
```

This is blocking rendering for me because it is passing down these on `render()` because I'm mapping the values as such:

```
render()
{
    return(
           <div>
           {this.props.Obj.hours.map((h) => 
               <rhourComponent hours={h.hours} />
           )}
           </div>
          );
}
```

So, I end up with 3 components with Zero as value.

Any idea why this can happen?

This is a React SPFx Client-Side Webpart.

Comment: can you update question with your `rhourComponent `? one more at time of consoling the values in `foreach` callback you are getting iterator as `rt` and consoling as `tr`, is it type in posting question or typo in your code?

Comment: That was a typo in the code for the question. The actual code works well.
The this is weird because if I do console.log(rTimes) it shows me the 3 object in the array when I expand the objects in the console. But if I do for instance console.log (Obj.rTimes[1].hours) it also shows me 0.

Answer (score 1):

`rTimes` objects are likely being updated after the component is rendered.

I would try:

1. outputting through the console each of the array objects to verify if `idH` is being updated;
2. encapsulate the `forEach` in a `setTimeout`;
3. avoid using the component props directly in the JSX by assigning them to an internal component variable and than mapping that array instead.

An example of (3):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    hours: this.props.Obj.hours
  };
}
```

And then on the JSX:

```
<div>
{this.state.hours.map((h) => 
    <rhourComponent hours={h} />
)}
</div>
```

Or (in passing the entire array):

```
<div>
    <rhourComponent hours={this.state.hours} />
</div>
```

You can then manipulate `hours` like so:

```
this.setState(
  update(this.state, {
    hours: [], // any array you want to change to
  }),
);
```

Comment: I'm setting the state in the main component and passing down as props. Should I pass the props into the state of the child components and then use the state to their childs?
I have now used Object.assign to clone the objects before passing them down so they don't update the original references.
Also I have a callback that updates the values in their textboxes up on the main component and sets the state there only.

Comment: The `rhourComponent` can have its own state with the hour(s) being set in its constructor (through the props you pass). Assigning to the state avoids props objects reading issues. Furthermore by using `update` from [*immutability-helper*](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html) the entire state is reset based on the old state and only the objects that you want to change are updated (avoids `Object.assign`).

Comment: I'll take a look into the immutability-helper. That may make my code simpler. I'm also trying to migrate this to React 16.8 so I can use Hooks. Let's see where this is going because all this behavior is looking strange to me.